# getting fatel error when trying to apply featured-posts-slideshow wp-plugin

Tags: wordpress

1. Error occured while trying to apply this plugin in my template page
   like this:-
2. Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in
   /wp-content/plugins/featured-posts-slideshow/featured-posts.php on
   line 2
3. Please help its urgent.Thanks in advance

Comment: I just included <?php include ("http://192.168.1.101/Clayton1/wp-content/plugins/featured-posts-slideshow/featured-posts.php"); ?> to call featured-posts-slideshow plugin to my template page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead of your include function:

```
include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/featured-posts-slideshow/featured-posts.php');
```

Comment: If above not worked then please add following code in your plugin file at the top (i.e in featured-posts.php)
$serverpath = explode("wp-content",dirname(__FILE__));
include $serverpath[0]."wp-blog-header.php";